# line thickness (using tablet) doesn't work

Tags: sculpting

It seems like blender doesn't recognize line thickness. The menu shows pen pressure min and max but how to affect the radius?

Answer (score 2):

By default the pressure affects the brush strength only. To make the pressure affect the radius of the brush you have to activate the small toggle switch located just to the right of the radius value.
[image]

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved your problem